# rmarkdown version 1.11 throws errors on existing prerendered files

Tags: r, r-markdown

I have several learnr tutorials running on a shiny server. After updating rmarkdown to version 1.11 I get the following error message whenever there exists a prerendered HTML file:

> Error in file.exists(dep$src$file) : invalid 'file' argument
>
> Calls:  ... shiny_prerendered_html -> shiny_prerendered_prerender -> file.exists
>
> Execution halted

Versions 1.9 and 1.10 work fine.

Any idea/help would be highly appreciated!

I did not manage to produce a short example - all partial files seem to work. A full file can be downloaded [here](https://tquant.eu/documents/IRT.Rmd)

Comment: It works fine for me. If you are still struggling with this issue, try to save this .Rmd file into an empty folder and run the document again.

Comment: I still have the problem, and I tried it on two different systems (Windows & Linux)

Answer (score 0):

I also have the same problem, a very quick and dirty solution is to delete the index.html file before each new render, but hoping for a more structural solution.

Comment: Yeah, that works - but it is not suitable for an rmarksown document on a publicly available shiny server